# Swift IOS: control incoming calls

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie in IOS development. I'm trying figure out how can I control (answer, reject, mute) incoming calls.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE for iOS 10

We can now block unwanted calls.

Check the [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) framework

> The CallKit framework provides programmatic access to VoIP functionality, as well as call blocking and identification.

**For iOS 9**

You can't do that with your any application. These are system calls and you **cannot** reject, mute or control incoming calls by your development.

I don't know about jailbreak phones. May be you can do if you are in jailbreak mode and have access to private APIs.

But without jailbreak, you just can't do it.